# self-hosted WebAPI 2 / OData 4 app - all controllers working, but one

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, odata

I have an odd situation in my self-hosted (OWIN) WebAPI 2 / OData 4 app: 3 out of 4 controllers are working fine, but one controller gives me 404.
Here is my startup.cs file, in which I build my edm:

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web.Http;
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Microsoft.Owin.FileSystems;
using Microsoft.Owin.StaticFiles;
using Owin;
using Nancy;
using System.Web.OData.Builder;
using System.Web.OData.Extensions;
using System.Web.Http.Cors;
using CommonDataService.Models;

namespace SelfHostedWebApiDataService
{

    public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            // Configure Web API for self-host. 
            var config = new HttpConfiguration();

            var corsAttr = new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*", null);

            config.EnableCors(corsAttr);

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );

            ODataModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
            builder.EntitySet<ChangeMeasure>("ChangeMeasure");
            builder.EntitySet<Account>("Account");
            builder.EntitySet<AccountAlia>("AccountAlias");
            builder.EntitySet<AccountTool>("AccountTools");
            builder.EntitySet<Role>("Role");
            builder.EntitySet<Person>("Person");
            builder.EntitySet<AccountRolePerson>("AccountRolePerson");
            config.MapODataServiceRoute(
                routeName: "ODataRoute",
                routePrefix: null,
                model: builder.GetEdmModel());


            // Adding to the pipeline with our own middleware
            app.Use(async (context, next) =>
            {
                // Add Header
                context.Response.Headers["Product"] = "Common Data Service";

                // Call next middleware
                await next.Invoke();
            });

            // Custom Middleare
            app.Use(typeof(SelfHostedWebApiDataService.CustomMiddleware));

            // Web Api
            app.UseWebApi(config);

            // File Server
            var options = new FileServerOptions
            {
                EnableDirectoryBrowsing = true,
                EnableDefaultFiles = true,
                DefaultFilesOptions = { DefaultFileNames = {"index.html"}},
                FileSystem = new PhysicalFileSystem("Assets"),
                StaticFileOptions = { ContentTypeProvider = new SelfHostedWebApiDataService.CustomContentTypeProvider() }
            };

            app.UseFileServer(options);

            // Nancy
            app.UseNancy();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my entity in question:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace CommonDataService.Models
{
    public partial class AccountRolePerson
    {
        public AccountRolePerson()
        {
            this.Accounts = new List<Account>();
            this.People = new List<Person>();
            this.Roles = new List<Role>();
        }

        public int AccountRolePersonID { get; set; }
        public string AccountID { get; set; }
        public int PersonID { get; set; }
        public int RoleID { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Account> Accounts { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Person> People { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Role> Roles { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Here is the WebAPI/OData controller for this entity:

```
using CommonDataService.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Http.Cors;
using System.Web.OData;

namespace CommonDataService.Controllers
{
    [EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
    class AccountRolePersonController : ODataController
    {
        MALContext db = new MALContext();

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            db.Dispose();
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        [EnableQuery]
        public IQueryable<AccountRolePerson> Get()
        {
            return db.AccountRolePersons;
        }

        [EnableQuery]
        public SingleResult<AccountRolePerson> Get([FromODataUri] string key)
        {
            IQueryable<AccountRolePerson> result = db.AccountRolePersons.Where(p => p.AccountID == key);
            return SingleResult.Create(result);
        }
    }
}
```

When I enter my api url in fiddler:  `http://windows-10:8888/AccountRolePerson`, I get a 404, while other 3 controllers, associated with other entities, are working just fine.

Could anyone, please, help me find the reason for this odd situation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your controller is not a `public` class.